# Doubling numbers using a return statement in Javascript

Tags: javascript, return

I'm trying to solve this problem for class, the problem calls for us to create a function that takes a number and returns double that number.

The code I have is displaying the correct number's but I can't seem to figure out how to get the numbers to show on the appropriate line. With my code, all 3 equations are showing on each line. I can't seem to figure out how to specify each line to show the correct output and not the output of all 3.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

```js
function double(a) {
  return [4 * 2, 7 * 2, 2.4 * 2]
}

console.log('double(4):', double(4)); // 8
console.log('double(7):', double(7)); // 14
console.log('double(2.4):', double(2.4)); // 4.8

console.log('\n===\n');
```

**Output on the terminal...**

```
double(4): [ 8, 14, 4.8 ]

double(7): [ 8, 14, 4.8 ]

double(2.4): [ 8, 14, 4.8 ]
```

Comment: Why do you have `4, 7, and 2.4` hard-coded in the function? What if they call `double(10)`?

Comment: I wasn't sure, Its code my teacher wrote and asked us to modify to make it work based on the comments he left. I thought a stood for "anything".

Comment: Your teacher expects you to apply what you've learned about function arguments to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could return just that operation what the name suspects?

```
function double(v) {
    return v * 2;
}
```

Comment: Oh yikes, that was easier than I thought, I was overthinking the use of the variable. Thank you!